# Bullets in table

Tags: tables, formatting, bullets

I want to add bullet points to a simple table. However, I'm having trouble with formatting. The text is not spaced evenly and the last hline of the table overleaf would not accept

```
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
{
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
\hline
Pros& Cons &Price Range \\
\hline
\begin{itemize}
  \item Simple, easy to use
  \item Low cost to produce
  \item High versatility
\end{itemize}
& 
\flushleft
\begin{itemize}
    \item Poor durability
    \item Poor gripping strength for soft materials
\end{itemize}
& 
\flushleft
\begin{itemize}
    \item Poor durability
    \item Poor gripping strength for soft materials
\end{itemize}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{ Pros/Cons and Price Range for Category 1}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
}
```

Does any one have any advice?

Comment: Add a `\\ ` before the last `\hline`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7):

With the help of the `enumitem` package you can achieve the following result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textbullet,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
{
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
\hline
Pros& Cons &Price Range \\
\hline
\begin{tabitem}
  \item Simple, easy to use
  \item Low cost to produce
  \item High versatility
\end{tabitem}
& 

\begin{tabitem}
    \item Poor durability
    \item Poor gripping strength for soft materials
\end{tabitem}
& 

\begin{tabitem}
    \item Poor durability
    \item Poor gripping strength for soft materials
\end{tabitem}
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{ Pros/Cons and Price Range for Category 1}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: probably the dot after `\textbullet` is superfluous :-)

Comment: @Zarko: You're right. Seems as if this was a copy-paste-leftover that I have now removed.

Answer (score 5):

I have used a combination of `\usepackage{paralist}+{compactitem}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\makeatletter
\let\savespace\@minipagetrue
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
{
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ |p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|  }
\hline
Pros& Cons &Price Range \\
\hline
\begin{compactitem}
  \item Simple, easy to use
  \item Low cost to produce
  \item High versatility
\end{compactitem}
& 

\begin{compactitem}
    \item Poor durability
    \item Poor gripping strength for soft materials
\end{compactitem}
& 

\begin{compactitem}
    \item Poor durability
    \item Poor gripping strength for soft materials
\end{compactitem}
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{ Pros/Cons and Price Range for Category 1}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Some improvements with `hhline` for the intersections of vertical and horizontal lines, and a simpler code: I defines  a new `I` column type, based on `X`, which automatically enters and leaves  the itemize environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx, hhline}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{I}{>{\compress\itemize}X <{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= *, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |*{3}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}I|}}
\hhline{|---|}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Pros} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Cons} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Price Range} \\
\hhline{|---|}
  \item Simple, easy to use
  \item Low cost to produce
  \item High versatility
&
    \item Poor durability
    \item Poor gripping strength for soft materials
&
    \item Poor durability
    \item Poor gripping strength for soft materials \\
\hhline{|---|}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{ Pros/Cons and Price Range for Category 1}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]