# Help creating the following table in Latex (bullet lists and merged cells)?

Tags: tables

Could someone please help me create the following table? There are 3 columns and 3 rows. The second and third rows of the second column are merged. Also, this merged column along with the last column (both rows) contain bulleted lists. [image: Picture of Table]

Edit: Examples of what column 1/2 could be is "Similarities/Differences." Type 1 and 2 are what is being compared/contrasted. Thus, Column 1 is merged because they are similar.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have tried so far? For the first column, you might want to use `\multirow`. Regarding the lists, you might be interested in [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430218/134144)

Comment: Could you please also add some explanation regarding the layout of your table? How are for example "Type 1" and "Category 1" related?

Answer (score 2):

I tried my best to write this code and hopefully it will be helpful.
These links helped me to write this code:

https://www.latex-tables.com/

[Bullet point list inside of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329008/bullet-point-list-inside-of-a-table/329023)

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
%\cline{1-3}
  & Column 1       & Column 2    \\
\cline{1-3}
Type 1 & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{p{0.4\textwidth} p{.03\textwidth} p{0.4\textwidth}}
Category1
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2 Item 2 Item 2 \newline Item 2 Item 2
  \end{itemize}
\\\\Category2
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 \newline Item 1 Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}} 

& \begin{tabular}[c]{p{0.4\textwidth} p{.03\textwidth} p{0.4\textwidth}}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Diff1
  \item Diff2
  \item Diff3
  \end{itemize}

\end{tabular}   \\


\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
Type 2 &                                                                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{p{0.4\textwidth} p{.03\textwidth} p{0.4\textwidth}}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Diff4
  \item Diff5 Diff5 Diff5 Diff5 \newline Diff5 Diff5  
  \item Diff6
  \end{itemize}

\end{tabular} &   \\
  &                                                                                                &        
               &  \\

%\cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

.
.

The result:

[image]

Maybe for the formatting, you can play with the spacing, font size .. etc. Or you can use some commands to resize the table.

Regards,