# Itemize in TabularX: How to remove new line before items?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx, itemize, enumitem, vspace

Consider the following **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| p{2cm} | p{2cm} |}
        Text &  \begin{itemize}
                    \item Text
                    \item Text
                \end{itemize}
                \\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

The behavior of `\itemize` to let its `items` begin in a new line looks ugly in this case.

How could I get it like this?

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

I would prefer to avoid using a messy `\vspace{-...pt}` with hardcoded values to shift the `items` up.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430218/134144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| p{2cm} | p{2cm} |}
        Text &\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname  \begin{itemize}
                    \item Text
                    \item Text
                \end{itemize}
                \\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a macro I found on this site,which makes LaTeX believe the cell is a minipage. However, there remains a vertical spacing at the bottom of the cell. This problem can be solved with `enumitem`, adding a negative vertical spacing at the end of the list. In addition, I advise to use the option `wide=0pt` in tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{|X | >{\compress}X|}
 Some text & Some more other\\
        Text & \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, after =\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
                    \item Text
                    \item Text
                \end{itemize}
                \\
 Another text & Still another
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that some characters slipped into the first line of your example source after you compiled the shown result? (`& Some A SCAmore ...`)? Just a tiny thing you might wanna fix to not confuse noobies like me - otherwise beatiful and useful solution :)

Comment: @MaxAxeHax: Looks very much like a copy-paste accident. I don't always think of checking. Thank you for warning me!