# Itemize in tabular: spurious vertical whitespace around items

Tags: tables, itemize, vertical-spacing

I have an `itemize` list inside a `p` table cell, and end up with unwanted vertical whitespace space before and after the list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
I don't want the extra vertical space preceding the bulleted list:
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item hello
   \end{itemize}
   &
   hello
\end{tabular}

I want something more like:
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item hello
   \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
   hello
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

What's the simplest/most idiomatic way to avoid this?

**Edit:** prepending the `itemize` environment with `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` works. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501182/itemize-in-tabularx-how-to-remove-new-line-before-items

Comment: Thanks - didn’t find that one (`tabular` vs `tabularx`, I guess). Renamed my question to make the connection more explicit.

Comment: In the given link is not the point `tabularx` but definition of column type. It can be `p{...}` too! I will show you in my answer (asap)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if only the top vertical space is mater of concern, than solution provided by [Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501182/itemize-in-tabularx-how-to-remove-new-line-before-items) 's answer can help you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
I don't want the extra vertical space preceding the bulleted list:

\begin{tabular}{>{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname}p{4cm}p{4cm}} % insert minipages in cells
\hline  % for seeing the top tables's border
   \begin{itemize}
   \item hello
   \item hello also in the next item
   \end{itemize}
   &    hello   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, if you like to control more attributes of list in table, than you can do this by use of `enumitem` package and define new list, for example `tabitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}       
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list for use in tables
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin = *         ,
                  label      = $\bullet$ ,
                  after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }

\begin{document}
I don't want the extra vertical space preceding the bulleted list:

\begin{tabular}{>{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname}p{4cm}p{4cm}} % insert minipages in cells
\hline  % for seeing the top tables's border
   \begin{tabitem}
   \item hello
   \item hello also in the next item where is no space after end of list
   \end{tabitem}
   &    hello   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It may be handy, if you define new column type, for example

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
```

and than write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}       
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list for use in tables
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                  wide=0pt,  % <-- new "makeup" for list formatting
                             % see @Bernard's comment below
                  label      = $\bullet$ ,
                  after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
I don't want the extra vertical space preceding the bulleted list:

\begin{tabular}{P{4cm}p{4cm}} % insert minipages in cells
\hline  % for seeing the top tables's border
   \begin{tabitem}
   \item hello
   \item hello also in the next item where is no space after end of list
   \end{tabitem}
   &    hello   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

where is also considered @Bernard comment regarding list formatting. Above MWE (Minimal Working Example) gives:

[image]

Note: definition

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname}p{#1}}
```

is equivalent to definition:

```
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\@minipagetrue\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Bernard, you are right. I was to much focused on vertical spaces :-(.  I will add this possibilities to last example in answer (asap).

Comment: Thanks - I hadn’t noticed the additional trailing space, but on closer inspection I see it in my table, so this is my preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most effective way to avoid the extra space, is to redirect a @minipagetrue into the column by defining a special column, as demonstrated by @egreg in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242145/9632). I.e. you load the package [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array), define a new column type using redirection. Of course you may add other commands to the redirection, for example alignment, font attributes, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\@minipagetrue}p{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
I don't want the extra vertical space preceding the bulleted list:

\begin{tabular}{P{4cm}p{4cm}}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item hello
   \end{itemize}
   &
   hello
\end{tabular}

I want something more like:

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item hello
   \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
   hello
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```